# Retrofit, PHP. Получить данные юзера с бд

Tags: php, android, retrofit

Имеется две таблицы, одна с пользователями и другая с их данными (заметками). Использую retrofit, но не могу получить данные со второй таблицы (заметки). Как мне необходимо сформировать запрос. Вот, что есть сейчас.

```
@GET("folder/note.php")
Call<List<Note>> getNotes(
        @Path("email") String email
);

void getDate(String email){
    view.showLoading();

    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<List<Note>> call = apiInterface.getNotes(email);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Note>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Note>> call,@NonNull Response<List<Note>> response) {
            view.hideLoading();
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null){
                view.onGetResult(response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<Note>> call,@NonNull Throwable t) {
            view.hideLoading();
            view.onErrorLoading(t.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

И PHP скрипты
getEmail.php

```
<?php

require_once ('connect.php');

$email = $_POST['email'];

$getId = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE email='$email'");

?>
```

note.php

```
header("Content-type:application/json");

require_once ('connect.php');
require_once ("crypt.php");
require_once ("getEmail.php")

//$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id='$id' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `passwords` WHERE id='$getId'");

$response = array();

while ( $row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){

    $pass = mc_decrypt($row['pass'], ENCRYPTION_KEY);
    array_push($response,
    array(
        'id_pswd'    =>$row['id_pswd'],
        'title' =>$row['title'],
        'email' =>$row['email'],
        'pass'  =>$pass,
        'info'  =>$row['info'],
        'color' =>$row['color'],
        'date'  =>$row['date'])
    );
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: Обратите внимание, что в этом коде уязвимость к sql-инъекции. Не вставляйте пользовательские значения в запрос. В `$_POST['email']` может быть любой текст, в том числе символы, которые интерпретируются как часть sql-запроса. Используйте `mysqli_escape_string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, ваш метод использует GET-запрос, а в коде PHP вы пытаетесь получить переменную из POST-запроса, то есть вам скорее всего нужно использовать $_GET или же $_REQUEST.

Во-вторых, значение @Path-переменной используется для форматирования строки запроса (пути) "folder/note.php", если в нем есть метка с соответствующем именем, то есть, например "folder/note.php/{email}". Тут нужно использовать либо @Field, либо @Query.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала нужно проверить что в переменной $email находится. Для этого просто выведите ее после определения. Например вот так:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

echo $email;
```

Дальше по простому если. Вы делаете запрос но не помещаете результат в переменную. Например вот так:

```
$getId = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE email='$email'");

$myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($getId);

// $myrow['id'] будет хранить ваш ID пользователя
```

Ну а потом уже делаете все остальное подставляя в запрос ID пользователя вот так:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `passwords` WHERE id='".$myrow['id']."'");

$response = array();

while ( $row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){

    $pass = mc_decrypt($row['pass'], ENCRYPTION_KEY);
    array_push($response,
    array(
        'id_pswd'    =>$row['id_pswd'],
        'title' =>$row['title'],
        'email' =>$row['email'],
        'pass'  =>$pass,
        'info'  =>$row['info'],
        'color' =>$row['color'],
        'date'  =>$row['date'])
    );
}
```